# Segue UI Image to ViewController with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage, segue

I'm trying to pass an uiimage to my secondViewController but keep running into an error with my coding.  How can i segue uiimage to my secondViewController?

viewController.swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "test") {

       let destViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController

        destViewController.mainpictures = "background"
    }
```

SecondViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var mainpictures = String ()

    @IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.mainImage.text = mainpictures

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about "an error"?   Actually, a **lot** more specific would be good!

Comment: I'm getting an error UIIMageView does not have a member name "text".  I thinking the error is located at the self.mainImage.text = mainpictures.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  According to the documentation, a `UIImageView` does not, in fact, have a `text` property.

Comment: it really should be self.mainImage.image = mainpicture..but I'm getting an error on that too.  What would be the code to resolve the uiimage problem?

Comment: `mainpictures` is a string; `self.mainImage.image` requires a `UIImage`.  I have no idea why you would expect that to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code

```
if let image = UIImage(named: mainpictures) {
     self.mainImage.image = image
}
```

instead of this

```
self.mainImage.text = mainpictures
```